# Give a reasonable bound for the error

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

SO the question is as follows
[image]

I understand that a decimal approximation of sin 1.1 yields 0.891207...

So using the Taylor polynomial of sin(x) about a= 0, I'll get a series expansion like this
[image]

Into which I could plug 1.1 in for x and get some number reasonably close to the true value. I'm not exactly sure what to take from this knowledge to get what this question is asking. What would an error bound in terms of "1.1 and k" look like?

Comment: Just have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Taylor theorem in the form:

$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + ... +\frac{f^{n}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n +R_{n+1}
$$
Where the remainder $R_{n+1}=\frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$ where $\xi$ lies between $a$ and $x$ (or one of the other forms for the remainder)